# Deploy parse app using "git push"

Tags: parse-platform

I was wondering if there is a way to deploy my nodejs app to Parse using just `git push`, I mean without using the CLI (because I've downloaded the CLI but I can't examine its source code).

Comment: Related on Programmers.SE: [How to make a “git push” update files on your web host?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/210854/40980)

Comment: Well, it's related but at the same time it isn't :p. I mean, yes, it's about deploying using git push, but it doesn't mention parse.com (actually, I know how to deploy using git push on my own servers). Thanks anyway.